# A linear code must be able to send $256$ different messages s.t. it corrects one error. What is the least possible length of such a code?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I'm studying for exam that is coming up and I'm reading about correcting errors in linear code and I'm struggling with this problem. Any solutions? Thanks!

Suppose we wish to be able to send $256$ different messages by means of a linear code which will correct one error.
(a) What is the least possible length of such a code?
(b) Find a lower bound for the length of the code if two errors
are to be corrected.

Comment: Have you tried to solve simpler problems of this kind?

Comment: No, any tips on where I should start?

Comment: The columns of the parity check matrix of a single error correcting code must be non-zero and distinct. How many rows do you need to achieve that keeping in mind that the number of columns must exceed the numbre of rows by eight.

Comment: @BLCAAN I mean suppose you only need $2$ different messages. How could you correct one error? Then try it with $4$ different messages. This will allow you to build up intuition  about the solution. Also it will show that you actually can do some work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to  MSE!
I'd consider the Hamming bound,
$$q^n \geq |C|\sum_{i=0}^t {n\choose i}(q-1)^i,$$
where $|C|=2^8$, $q=2$, $d=2t+1=3$, i.e., $t=1$.

Search for the smallest block length $n\geq 8$ such that this inequality is satisfied.